# How to make MSWord auto fill cells with days of week?

Tags: ms-word, autofill, autoformatting

here i want to make microsoft word autofill it for me with days

And i want to just fill with the next numbers all rows below.
[image: table]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some Googling and it looks like Word does have a table formula feature. However it looks pretty simple. I couldn't get it to automatically changed the referenced cell when I copy/pasted like it does in Excel.

The formula feature is located at Table Tools -> Layout -> Formula.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-a-formula-in-a-word-table-HA102329800.aspx

Maybe you could try a Calendar Wizard? New -> Office.com Templates -> Calendar? I've used that a couple of times before and it's made me some nice looking calendars. They don't dynamically update, but you can tell it exactly how many pages to generate for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: heh, i don't even remember the question and why i asked it.... but anyways, i will accept it as answer since you did great job! thanks